# Tryton view doesn't appear

Tags: tryton

Developing a module with Tryton 4.6.0

I can' t manage to make a simple tree view appear

[Here](https://gitlab.com/devincentis.emilio/tributi/blob/master/tributi.xml)'s the relevant code. What's wrong with it ?

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX3Vz.jpg)'s a picture

Comment: I see the "Processing" widget is visible. Often it means there was an exception when processing a request. You just take a look at the javascript console.

Comment: in the concole I see some javascript resource can' t be reached: Unchecked lastError value: Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. ExtensionCommon.jsm:407

Comment: did I mess up the SAO installation ? How ?

Comment: anyway, this happens on the other menus too. Only mine is unable to show a view